# How to use other DB connection in strapi?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, redis, strapi

So in my `/config/environments/*/database.json` under my `connections` field, I declared another DB connection to redis.

I know accesing the model will fall down to the default ( which is `MongoDB` for this scenario), but how can I use my redis connection if I want to use it instead of the default?

Answer (score -1):

If you are using the content type builder plugin to create a new content type, in the modal where you chose the content type name, you will see a dropdown for the connection you want to use.

If you have already created the content type, in the `./api/:name/models/:Name.settings.json` file you will see a `connection` key.
You will have to replace the value with your connection name.

Comment: So if I'm gonna use it ( in my case, the new DB is `redis` ), it will be `strapi.models.[:api].[:modelname].set()/get()` ?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do with the line you wrote.

Comment: how can i connect with redis

Comment: It's not possible to connect to Redis